# Aspnet Core Identity Redirects to HTTP even UseHttpsRedirection defined in startup

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Having scaffolded the Identity Area in Aspnet Core 2.1. with this startup class:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // AppSettings.json
        //
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ProvidersSettings"));

        // IdentityUser settings
        //
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            // All MvcControllers are hereby "Authorize". Use AllowAnonymous to give anon access
            //
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        });

        // IdentityModel
        //
        services.AddSingleton<IDiscoveryCache>(r =>
        {
            var url = Configuration["ProvidersSettings:IdentityServerEndpoint"];

            var factory = r.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            return new DiscoveryCache(url, () => factory.CreateClient());
        });

        // HttpContext injection
        //
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

It works in development. But in production it doesn't stay on **https**. It redirects to **http** and this path:

> /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

On localhost it works correctly with both IIS express and "program".

Any ideas are most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you mind sharing your entire Configure() method?  Seems like order of events might play part?  If you are using Visual Studio w/IIS Express, is "Enable SSL" checked in the project's Debug options?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have added the entire startup class. Yes "enable ssl" is checked. It also works when using the "program" setting. In production the "Require IIS" is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks!  Have you tried putting `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` at the top of the chain?  before `if (env.IsDevelopment()` ?

Comment: Yes, that still redirects to http. :/